# Is there any OS-level caching for bare block devices? If so, how do I bypass it?

Tags: block-device, caching

If I read and write directly to a block device (e.g. `/dev/sda1`), is there any OS-level caching involved on Linux? If so, how do I bypass it, is opening with `O_DIRECT` enough?

I'm writing a simple benchmark script to characterize the behavior of a shingled magnetic recording (SMR) drive I have, so I don't want to bypass any drive-level caching or reordering, only anything the OS is doing.

Searching for the relevant terms gives lots of results that do not address this specific question, though I did learn that Solaris and FreeBSD have both block and character devices for disks, with the block devices being buffered. On my Linux I only see block devices for disks.

Answer (score 0):

> If I read and write directly to a block device (e.g. /dev/sda1), is there any OS-level caching involved on Linux?

For Linux, yes, absolutely.

> If so, how do I bypass it, is opening with O_DIRECT enough?

For Linux it must be.

I know nothing about other UNIXes, but I presume most apply here as well.